# Trying To Scrape HTML After JavaScript Using Python... No Luck

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I've tried just about everything... PyQt5, Selenium, BS4, requests_html, etc... Still cannot get what I'm looking for.

I am trying to web scrape the data from `https://www.tokenanalyst.io/exchange` , specifically these dollar values. It appears as though this data is generated AFTER some Javascript code. I have not been able to successfully scrape said data. Is anyone able to successfully return the HTML code or integers?

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is a bit unclear. It did not show what methods you tried.
For the websites similar to that, you can't use beautiful soup. However, Selenium and chromedriver would be a nice choice since you can always scrape html for data.
You have to [locate what you want to scrape](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)
But to me, this method is a bit slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse JSON values from their API:

```
import requests
import json

exchanges = ['Bitfinex', 'Binance', 'Bitstamp', 'Bittrex', 'Poloniex', 'BitMEX']

data = {}
for e in exchanges:
    url_inflow = 'https://api.tokenanalyst.io/analytics/last?job=btc_{}_{}_24h_rolling_v5&format=json'.format(e, 'inflow')
    url_outflow = 'https://api.tokenanalyst.io/analytics/last?job=btc_{}_{}_24h_rolling_v5&format=json'.format(e, 'outflow')

    j_inflow = json.loads(requests.get(url_inflow).text)
    j_outflow = json.loads(requests.get(url_outflow).text)

    print(e)
    print(j_inflow)
    print(j_outflow)

    data[e] = (j_inflow[0]['inflow_usd'], j_outflow[0]['outflow_usd'])

print('*' * 80)

for k, v in data.items():
    print('Exchange: {} Inflow_USD: {} Outflow_USD: {}'.format(k, v[0], v[1]))
```

Prints:

```
Bitfinex
[{'avg_txn_value': 3.4021, 'entity': 'Bitfinex', 'inflow': 945.79000615, 'number_of_entity_receiving_addresses': 246, 'number_of_nonentity_sending_addresses': 1427, 'number_of_txns': 278, 'period_ending_at': '2019-06-17T22:12:27.500Z', 'inflow_usd': 8707062.91194768, 'avg_txn_value_usd': 31320.164666700002, 'inflow_usd_pct_change': '-54.67230315707747', 'avg_txn_value_usd_pct_change': '-47.98800964713564', 'inflow_pct_change': '-55.32126412430956', 'avg_txn_value_pct_change': '-48.7326702833032'}]
[{'avg_txn_value': 3.199, 'entity': 'Bitfinex', 'number_of_entity_sending_addresses': 245, 'number_of_nonentity_receiving_addresses': 644, 'number_of_txns': 258, 'outflow': 2060.15622225, 'period_ending_at': '2019-06-17T22:12:21.346Z', 'outflow_usd': 18966059.82187373, 'avg_txn_value_usd': 29450.400273, 'outflow_usd_pct_change': '-16.706252918178574', 'avg_txn_value_usd_pct_change': '-33.13281601840719', 'outflow_pct_change': '-17.898777454731185', 'avg_txn_value_pct_change': '-34.09015988132521'}]
Binance
[{'avg_txn_value': 3.6763, 'entity': 'Binance', 'inflow': 13205.11846359, 'number_of_entity_receiving_addresses': 3282, 'number_of_nonentity_sending_addresses': 24453, 'number_of_txns': 3592, 'period_ending_at': '2019-06-17T22:12:35.270Z', 'inflow_usd': 121569489.80424081, 'avg_txn_value_usd': 33844.900111999996, 'inflow_usd_pct_change': 78.7755357787967, 'avg_txn_value_usd_pct_change': 75.14686308991297, 'inflow_pct_change': 76.21343804513097, 'avg_txn_value_pct_change': 72.6367691946466}]
[{'avg_txn_value': 1.2547, 'entity': 'Binance', 'number_of_entity_sending_addresses': 1, 'number_of_nonentity_receiving_addresses': 9317, 'number_of_txns': 151, 'outflow': 11689.74225155, 'period_ending_at': '2019-06-17T22:12:25.426Z', 'outflow_usd': 107617251.76503526, 'avg_txn_value_usd': 11550.9275469, 'outflow_usd_pct_change': 18.73881008764625, 'avg_txn_value_usd_pct_change': 27.803672981371243, 'outflow_pct_change': 17.03881519689553, 'avg_txn_value_pct_change': 25.97389558232931}]
Bitstamp
[{'avg_txn_value': 4.9848, 'entity': 'Bitstamp', 'inflow': 4845.21760603, 'number_of_entity_receiving_addresses': 363, 'number_of_nonentity_sending_addresses': 5109, 'number_of_txns': 972, 'period_ending_at': '2019-06-18T03:13:29.366Z', 'inflow_usd': 44827992.052730404, 'avg_txn_value_usd': 46119.4094784, 'inflow_usd_pct_change': 20.9229998843688, 'avg_txn_value_usd_pct_change': 12.338050679950097, 'inflow_pct_change': 19.18043979551204, 'avg_txn_value_pct_change': 10.71920394473812}]
[{'avg_txn_value': 2.1021, 'entity': 'Bitstamp', 'number_of_entity_sending_addresses': 211, 'number_of_nonentity_receiving_addresses': 2818, 'number_of_txns': 86, 'outflow': 5923.80448966, 'period_ending_at': '2019-06-17T22:05:56.784Z', 'outflow_usd': 54531167.56325086, 'avg_txn_value_usd': 19350.734403000002, 'outflow_usd_pct_change': 23.4058365064299, 'avg_txn_value_usd_pct_change': '-13.467075488325623', 'outflow_pct_change': 21.635752626972593, 'avg_txn_value_pct_change': '-14.70826909031891'}]
Bittrex
[{'avg_txn_value': 0.455, 'entity': 'Bittrex', 'inflow': 613.35675971, 'number_of_entity_receiving_addresses': 1362, 'number_of_nonentity_sending_addresses': 4700, 'number_of_txns': 1348, 'period_ending_at': '2019-06-18T03:13:29.480Z', 'inflow_usd': 5674781.647690997, 'avg_txn_value_usd': 4209.66364, 'inflow_usd_pct_change': '-3.5874967447576775', 'avg_txn_value_usd_pct_change': '-15.028043006702655', 'inflow_pct_change': '-4.976848484294497', 'avg_txn_value_pct_change': '-16.252530830112274'}]
[{'avg_txn_value': 0.326, 'entity': 'Bittrex', 'number_of_entity_sending_addresses': 1396, 'number_of_nonentity_receiving_addresses': 2029, 'number_of_txns': 154, 'outflow': 661.49258585, 'period_ending_at': '2019-06-17T22:05:52.827Z', 'outflow_usd': 6089323.694561165, 'avg_txn_value_usd': 3000.9701800000003, 'outflow_usd_pct_change': '-15.905765601357832', 'avg_txn_value_usd_pct_change': '-24.950292648797074', 'outflow_pct_change': '-17.11197960936857', 'avg_txn_value_pct_change': '-26.026775584297702'}]
Poloniex
[{'avg_txn_value': 0.9987, 'entity': 'Poloniex', 'inflow': 551.29290849, 'number_of_entity_receiving_addresses': 688, 'number_of_nonentity_sending_addresses': 2832, 'number_of_txns': 552, 'period_ending_at': '2019-06-18T03:13:29.395Z', 'inflow_usd': 5100566.399692748, 'avg_txn_value_usd': 9239.9803896, 'inflow_usd_pct_change': 40.079661028653504, 'avg_txn_value_usd_pct_change': 8.863578042174874, 'inflow_pct_change': 38.06104400126806, 'avg_txn_value_pct_change': 7.294800171895152}]
[{'avg_txn_value': 0.5784, 'entity': 'Poloniex', 'number_of_entity_sending_addresses': 2, 'number_of_nonentity_receiving_addresses': 1048, 'number_of_txns': 302, 'outflow': 606.13545851, 'period_ending_at': '2019-06-17T22:05:48.914Z', 'outflow_usd': 5579737.53383171, 'avg_txn_value_usd': 5324.420712, 'outflow_usd_pct_change': '-8.109879467421727', 'avg_txn_value_usd_pct_change': '-21.789008537427183', 'outflow_pct_change': '-9.427914542915346', 'avg_txn_value_pct_change': '-22.9108356657337'}]
BitMEX
[{'avg_txn_value': 0.6535, 'entity': 'Bitmex', 'inflow': 2120.51020525, 'number_of_entity_receiving_addresses': 3392, 'number_of_nonentity_sending_addresses': 10107, 'number_of_txns': 3245, 'period_ending_at': '2019-06-18T03:13:29.505Z', 'inflow_usd': 19618977.383054644, 'avg_txn_value_usd': 6046.187228, 'inflow_usd_pct_change': '-41.10742264036966', 'avg_txn_value_usd_pct_change': '-33.7342645462863', 'inflow_pct_change': '-41.95609373631447', 'avg_txn_value_pct_change': '-34.68918648810713'}]
[{'avg_txn_value': 1.9551, 'entity': 'Bitmex', 'number_of_entity_sending_addresses': 2101, 'number_of_nonentity_receiving_addresses': 2063, 'number_of_txns': 2231, 'outflow': 4033.36989488, 'period_ending_at': '2019-06-17T22:06:16.970Z', 'outflow_usd': 37128904.2314252, 'avg_txn_value_usd': 17997.536193, 'outflow_usd_pct_change': 247.60891113166488, 'avg_txn_value_usd_pct_change': 97.97896643193221, 'outflow_pct_change': 242.62294817100863, 'avg_txn_value_pct_change': 95.13923545264}]
********************************************************************************
Exchange: Bitfinex Inflow_USD: 8707062.91194768 Outflow_USD: 18966059.82187373
Exchange: Binance Inflow_USD: 121569489.80424081 Outflow_USD: 107617251.76503526
Exchange: Bitstamp Inflow_USD: 44827992.052730404 Outflow_USD: 54531167.56325086
Exchange: Bittrex Inflow_USD: 5674781.647690997 Outflow_USD: 6089323.694561165
Exchange: Poloniex Inflow_USD: 5100566.399692748 Outflow_USD: 5579737.53383171
Exchange: BitMEX Inflow_USD: 19618977.383054644 Outflow_USD: 37128904.2314252
```

Comment: Thanks a bajillion for the detailed and fast response. Sorry for the silly question, but where did you find the documentation for public API endpoints? I'm still new to python and am trying to learn when I can. Im trying to also access on-chain volume.

Comment: Not sure if this is how he did it. But if you go to the page you linked and (if you are on chrome) open Developer Tools, go to Network tab, and clear anything that's already there. Then click on Binance for example, you can see a bunch of requests that were made by the website. He probably sorted through them to see which ones he needed.